# How do I adjust the table link endpoint in PgAdmin's ERD tool after autogenerating it from an existing database?

Tags: postgresql, erd, pgadmin

I can move the lines themselves around, but I can't move the endpoints, which cause the lines to overlap.  The only way to understand which relationship is being referenced is by hovering over the connection.  A printout of a complex ERD becomes unusable.

I can move the tables and the lines themselves, but cannot move the endpoints.

[image: Confusing overlap]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In response to the community bot: He wants to change the link so that it links different tables together. I haven't found a way to do this, but if you select the link then click the bin (trashcan) icon, it will remove it; then you can re-create it however you like.

Answer (score 2):

In version 6.10, one action that seems to help is to drag one segment parallel towards another and beyond, this automatically erases the extra perpendicular segment. It works by dragging only one of the segments and not the other (apparently the one closer to the table). See attached images for clarification.

[image: Before] [image: After]